# If key value pair exists in Object then update it else add it in an object

Tags: javascript

I have a blank object which I need to update on user action.

```
let userAction = {};
```

I have multiple buttons on page with unique ID's,

Like: Btn1, Btn2, whatever

So if as a user I will click Btn1 then my object should be updated with its id and number of click., Like this

```
userAction = {btn1: 1}
```

if I will click on bt2 then it would also update that object with its ID like this:

```
userAction = {btn1: 1, Btn2: 1 }
```

but if I will click any other button one more time then it should update the value by +1. Like this

So I click Btn1 again.. then object will look like this.

```
userAction = {btn1: 2, Btn2: 1 }
```

I tried to do it like this, just need to know is there any better or optimized option to do this.

```js
let userAction  = {};

$('button').click(function(){
  let btnId = $(this).attr('id');
  let exisitngValue = userAction[`${btnId}`];
if (btnId in userAction){
  userAction[`${btnId}`] = exisitngValue+1;
}else {
userAction[`${btnId}`] = 1;
}
console.log(userAction);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Btn1">Button 1</button>  
<button id="Btn2">Button 2</button>  
<button id="Btn3">Button 3</button>  
<button id="whatever">whatever</button>
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could take just the `id` of the button directly without a template string and assign directly the value or zero and add one.

```js
let userAction  = {};

$('button').click(function(){
  let btnId = $(this).attr('id');
  userAction[btnId] = (userAction[btnId] || 0) + 1;
  console.log(userAction);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Btn1">Button 1</button>  
<button id="Btn2">Button 2</button>  
<button id="Btn3">Button 3</button>  
<button id="whatever">whatever</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let userAction  = {};

$('button').click(function(){
  let btnId = $(this).attr('id');
  userAction[btnId]=userAction[btnId] ?  userAction[btnId]+1 : 1;
console.log(userAction);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Btn1">Button 1</button>  
<button id="Btn2">Button 2</button>  
<button id="Btn3">Button 3</button>  
<button id="whatever">whatever</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let userAction  = {};

$('button').click(function(){
   let btnId = $(this).attr('id');
   userAction[btnId] = userAction[btnId]+1 || 1;

   console.log(userAction);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Btn1">Button 1</button>  
<button id="Btn2">Button 2</button>  
<button id="Btn3">Button 3</button>  
<button id="whatever">whatever</button>
```